# Some icons with 2 parts in their name won't show up?

Tags: icons, font-awesome

For example: `class="icon-info"` Will work perfectly

But : `class="icon-info-circle"` Won't show up at all

Nt only this icon but any icon that has 2 parts ( include `-` in the name ) won't show?

my URL: http://www.behnam-design.com/tgfpizza/kontakt/

Answer (score 0):

In Font-Awesome 3.2.1 (which is the version you're using), there is no `icon-info-circle`. The icons which accept a `-circle` suffix are:

```
icon-ban
icon-ok
icon-remove
icon-play
```

`icon-info` does, however, have a circular icon, but this is suffixed with `-sign`:

```html
<i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
```

[This is what it looks like](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icon/info-sign/).

You can refer to the [Font-Awesome 3.2.1 documentation](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icons/) to see which icons are available.